# DateTime format on server

Tags: javascript, datetime, model-view-controller

I have multi select check-box to select report dates. User is choosing one or more report dates. I am using JavaScript to get selected dates:

```
var dateTime = new Date($(this).val()).toJSON();
```

I am passing selected dates to controller and creading query:

```
foreach (var reportDate in reportDates)
{
   predicateReportDate = predicateReportDate.Or(p => p.LastUpdateDate == reportDate.ReportDate);
}
```

Everything works fine locally but I found issue with date format when I deploy page to server.

Locally DateTime format is like

> '2017-04-21 00:00:00'

but on server I see totally different date:

> 4/20/2017 6:00:00 PM

It causes that filter does not work properly on server (no results are returned) because there is no report with that date.

Both:

> LastUpdateDate

and

> reportDate.ReportDate

are DateTimes (not strings)

Can you please help me with unifying date format?

Comment: are you saying that the day is off by 1 day, or you need to clear the time parts?

Comment: Try inspecting the time zones of each Date object. They're probably referring to exactly the same point in time, but the representation is adjusted to the local time zone of where the code is running.

Comment: maybe not the best solution, but I have used this before to ensure just the dates match. javascript `var date1 = new Date();
                                   date1.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);`

Comment: you might need to use UTC time to ensure they match on client and server

Comment: Take care to spell JavaScript to avoid search collision with Java.

Comment: I see this question (or very close equivalent) asked nearly every day.. What you are seeing is the difference between client and server timezones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did is:

I replaced line which reads date from filter:

```
var dateTime = new Date($(this).val()).toJSON();
```

with

```
var dateTime =  $(this).val().split(' ')[0];
```

It seems that `toJSON()` is converting date (I am using UTC) to local server timezone.